# Check if current page has given tag ID

Tags: tags

I am using custom taxonomies.

How to check if current page has `tag_ID = "XXX"` ?

If that is any help the URL form WordPress admin looks like this:

```
http://localhost/website/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?action=edit&taxonomy=company&ta‌g_ID=13&post_type=news
```

---

Update. Here is code which I'm currently using. Does not work.

```
<?php
function insert_news($company = 0)
{
    global $post;

    $count       = 0;
    $news_query  = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'news',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'company' => $company
    ));
    $total_count = $news_query->post_count;
    while ($news_query->have_posts()):
        $news_query->the_post();

        $count++;

        $tag_id = get_query_var('tag_id');

        if ($tag_id && $tag_id == '14') {
            // ID 14

        } else if ($tag_id && $tag_id == '13') {
            // ID 13


        } else if ($tag_id && $tag_id == '12') {
            // ID 12


        }
    endwhile;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the tags is inside the query, it is possible to check for this via get_query_var(); all objects inside the query.
For the tag ID ask with this code: `get_query_var( 'tag_ID' );` Also it is possible to check for tags, like `get_query_var( 'term' )` and the taxonomy `get_query_var( 'taxonomy' )`

So you can create an Loop with your tag data form your taxonomy; like

```
$wpq = array ( 
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'published',
    'taxonomy'=> get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ),
    'term'=> get_query_var( 'term' )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $wpq );
while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
```

So you can check:
`if ( 'your_tad_id`=== get_query_var( 'tag_ID' ) ) `

- An hint; if you will use the check via `$_REQUEST`-var; please filter this data or use only for if statements.

Answer (score 9):

```
if ( is_object_in_term( $post->ID, 'post_tag', 'tag_slug_or_name_or_id_or_array' ) ) 
   do_my_funky_stuff();
```

**Update**: Regarding the following comment:

> How to check if current page has tag_ID = "XXX" ?
>
> If that is any help the URL form WordPress admin looks like this:
>
> `...edit-tags.php?action=edit&taxonomy=company&ta‌g_ID=13&post_type=news`

So I'm guessing you mean "check if editing tag with ID X"?

```
if ( isset( $_REQUEST['tag_ID'] ) && $_REQUEST['tag_ID'] == X )
    do_my_funky_stuff();
```

You really must be a little clearer with your teminology ;)

Comment: Hmm.. it does not work. If that is any help the URL looks like this `http://localhost/website/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?action=edit&taxonomy=company&tag_ID=13&post_type=news`

Comment: @NewUser can you show the exact code that you used?

Comment: @Pekka - please see the update. Have not got a clue why this does not work.

Comment: Sorry, for the edit. I rolled it back - my mistake, with string/int on tag ID.

Answer (score 2):

If you're only interested in 3 subsequent tag_id's you could start with narrowing down your query, using $_POST['tag_id'] and 'tag__in':

```
$query_tag_id = $_POST['tag_id'];

$news_query  = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'news',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'company' => $company,
    'tag__in' => array( $query_tag_id-1, $query_tag_id, $query_tag_id+1 )
));
```

And you can refer back to the $query_tag_id variable in the if conditional tests, like:

```
if( $tag_id == ( $query_tag_id - 1 ) ) {
    // do stuff
}
if( $tag_id == $query_tag_id ) {
    // do stuff
}
if( $tag_id == ( $query_tag_id + 1 ) ) {
    // do stuff
}
```

I'd expect that the suggestion made by TheDeadMedic would do the trick when you combine it with the above. Like this for the middle if test:

```
if ( is_object_in_term( $post->ID, 'post_tag', $query_tag_id ) ) 
   do_my_funky_stuff();
```

Failing that you could always get all the tag ids for the active post in the while loop and use those in the if tests. So you'd have to replace

```
$tag_id = get_query_var('tag_id');
```

with:

```
$tags = get_the_tags();
$tag_ids = array();
if( $tags ) {
    foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {
        $tags_id[] = $tag->term_id;
    }
}    

if ( in_array( ( $query_tag_id - 1 ) , $tag_ids ) ) {
    // do stuff
}
etc.
```

If you're certain your posts are only going to have one tag, you could simplify things by using:

```
$tags = get_the_tags();
$tag_id = ( $tags ) ? $tags[0]->term_id : 0;

if( $tag_id == ( $query_tag_id - 1 ) ) {
    // do stuff
}
etc.
```

Update:
On a side note, get_query_var() does not work because it looks for the parameters you set in the query. You didn't set any tag_id in the query, so it does not return anything. So changing the query as I suggested at the start of my answer would get you a return value, but not one you could use.

Answer (score 1):

```
$url = "http://localhost/website/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?action=edit&taxonomy=company&ta‌g_ID=13&post_type=news";
if (strpos($url, "tag_ID=13")!==false){
     //Do stuff here if it is there
}
else {
     //Do Other Stuff here if it is not there
}
```

For WordPress' sake, throw that into a function in the functions.php and add a hook, like init (Bare in mind this would be specific just to that tag)
You could make it conditional by setting a couple variables and testing to see if it equals a particular value.

Comment: sorry. Small misunderstanding. The URL is coming from wordpress admin site. Not the site front-end. Thanks for your answer both using FIXED `URL as variable` is too "manual".

Answer (score 1):

Try globalizing $wp_query since your doing this within a function.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tested this, but it should work.

```
<?php
// Gets the current Post ID
function get_postID(){
    global $wp_query;
    $thePostID = $wp_query->post->ID;
    return $thePostID;
}

// Check for specified Term ID
function check_term_id($id){
    $postID = get_postID();
    $post = get_post($postID);
    $taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies($post->post_type);
    foreach($taxonomies as $taxonomy){
        $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, $taxonomy);
        if(!empty($terms)){
            for($i = 0; $i < count($terms); $i++){
                if($terms[$i]->term_id == $id){
                    $return = $terms[$i];
                } else{
                    $return = 'error';  
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $return;
}

$checkTerm = check_term_id('xxx');
if($checkTerm != 'error'){
    //Do something with the term data.
}
?>
```